# Viewing scene render (hidden and unhidden) rather than hide in viewport

Tags: rendering

So, I have a lot of objects coming in and out of view for my animation. I find it VERY HARD to get an idea of what the render will look like when the viewport defaults to the eyeball (hide in viewport) and not the camera (disable in renders). I have the items keyframed in and out in the renders but, I cannot see this final result until I render it and that just does not work.

How can I change this?

(Thanks to whoever down-voted me trying to learn a program?)

Comment: Why not keyframe *restrict Viewport visibility* and *restrict render visibility* both?

Comment: Amazing solution! I could not find that anywhere but, stumbled upon it when desperately searching. I am new to blender and was unaware that there was this function as well. Is there any way to link the two so that I do not have to put in keyframes for each one every time (since they will be input the in the same places for my uses)?

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable both restriction toggles.

   [image: disable]

   - Disable in Viewports
   - Disable in Renders
2. Two options

   - Change or Keyframe them both.

     [image: keyframes]
   - Add a driver. Go to the Edit > User Preferences and enable *Auto Run Python Scripts*.

     [image: auto run python scripts]

     Add a driver to the Viewport Visiblity property, by clicking on its screen icon with a right click an choosing *Add Driver*. In the drivers popup (or in the Driver Editor), set the Type to *Scripted Expression*, enable *Use Self* and enter the Expression `self.hide_render`. This will change the value of the Viewport Visibility property to whatever value the Render Visibility is changed to.

     [image: add driver]

     It is now "connected" to the Render Visibility via the driver and any changes of the Render Visibility will directly be copied on the Viewport Visibility and be visible in the Viewport. (This also works for keyframed values.)

Comment: Ah! I didn't think you were going to bother with drivers.. I thought you were just going to use the timeline as a switch/slider between various visibility states during modelling.

Comment: In this case, drivers are too convenient to not use them.

Comment: Holy Cow times 500. I am new to blender and this is some advanced stuff for me but, I am going to do it on my next project and am so grateful for this! I literally owe you big time.

Comment: Cool, if this answer solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted, by ticking the checkmark at the top left of the answer.